# Reading SPSS 'code' file in JAVA

Tags: java, spss

The CIS provides the data from their surveys in an SPSS format (see explanation in Spanish [here](http://datos.cis.es/pdf/Instrucciones%20MD/ES_Instrucciones%20MD.pdf) ) and an example of the two file that correspond to a survey [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_r0yHhOf9vBVkxZWlRKYlFTSXc).

There is one file that looks as a list of SPSS instructions, is there a Java library that can parse those files and transform this into a Java structure ?

If no, what would be the smartest way to have this data in Java (I don't have an SPSS license :-) )?

A few lines of the SPSS file

```
DATA LIST FILE= 'DA3131' -> it's the file with data
/ESTU 1-4 CUES 5-9 CCAA 10-11 PROV 12-13 MUN 14-16 TAMUNI 17 CAPITAL 18 DISTR 19-20 SECCION 21-23
ENTREV 24-27 P0 28 P0A 29-31 P1 32 P2 33 P3 34 P4 35 P5 36 P6 37 P701 38-39 P702 40-41 P703 42-43
... continues like this 
EXECUTE.
FREQUENCIES VARIABLES ALL.
```

Comment: That is not an SPSS file, it looks like an SPS file which is SPSS syntax.

Basically it is a list of instructions for SPSS to run on a data file. Think of it as SPSS 'code' or a macro which is run by the SPSS engine.

Comment: Thanks. I've change the title, the problem remains the same

Answer (score 1):

The DA file has the actual data in it, the ES file is an spss syntax file which contains additional information about the data structure, labels for variables and for different values in every variable and a definition of missing values. Except for a frequency command there are no transformations or analysis of data in the syntax.

Comment: Additionally, given the command, the `DA3131` file is a text file with a specific fixed width specification. So the first variable `ESTU` takes up columns 1 to 4, `CUES` takes up 5 to 9, etc. And they are likely all numbers.